# jqgrid edit button link not working when i use onSelectRow event

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jqgrid

i am using jqgrid one grid contain master data and other grid contain detail data , when i click master grid row detail will show in detail grid (Master detail) so i am using onselectRow event i want to use edit button link in master when i use previous code then onselectrow event not fire and data not show in master grid , and this code working good in master detail grid . kindly expert tell what is the problem when i use edit button link in master grid then why event not fire .

Jqgrid

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        // master grid
        var $grid = $("#jqGrid");
        $grid.jqGrid({
            url: '@Url.Action("RequisitionGrid")',
            datatype: "json",
            jsonReader: { id: 'Req_ID' },
            colModel: [
                { name: 'Req_ID', index: 'Req_ID', label: 'Req ID', hidden: true, editable: true, editable: "disabled", align: "center", width: 12 },
                { name: 'Comp_ID', index: 'Comp_ID', label: 'Comp ID', hidden: true, editable: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['cn'] }, align: "left", width: 2 },
                { name: 'GL_Year', index: 'GL_Year', label: 'GL Year', hidden: true, editable: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['cn'] }, align: "left",  width: 40 },
                {
                    name: 'ReqDate', index: 'ReqDate', label: 'Date', width: 3,
                    editable: true, edittype: 'text',
                    editoptions: {
                        size: 10, maxlengh: 10,

                        dataInit: function (element) {
                            $(element).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd' })
                        }
                    }
                },
                { name: 'Job', index: 'Job', label: 'Job', width: 15, editable: true },

                { name: 'ApprovedBy', index: 'ApprovedBy', label: 'Approved by', width: 7, editable: true },
                { name: 'IsApproved', index: 'IsApproved', hidden: true, label: 'Approved', width: 10, editable: true },



                {
                    name: 'Req_ID', label: '', search: false, width: '3', formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject, rowdata) {
                        function MethodFormatter(cellValue, options, rowObject) {
                            var selectedRowId = options.rowId;
                            return '<a href="javascript:ReqMainUpdateMethod(' + selectedRowId + ')" style="color: #3366ff" id="' + selectedRowId + '" >Edit</a>';
                        }

                    }
                },


            ],

            height: 250,
            shrinkToFit: true,
            search: true,
            autowidth: true,
            rowNum: 20,
            viewrecords: true,
            page: 1,
            scroll: 1,
            viewrecords: true,
            rownumbers: true, // show row numbers
            rownumWidth: 25,
            navOptions: {
                reloadGridOptions: { fromServer: true }
            },
            formEditing: {

                closeOnEscape: true,
                closeAfterEdit: true,
                savekey: [true, 13],
                reloadGridOptions: {

                    fromServer: true
                }
            },
            forceClientSorting: true,

            loadonce: true,
            caption: 'Requisition Main',
            emptyrecords: 'No Records are Available to Display',
            onSelectRow: function (ids) {
                if (ids != null) {
                    var data = $("#jqGrid").getRowData(ids);
                    $("#jqGridDetails").jqGrid('setGridParam', { url: "/Home/RequisitionDetailGrid/" + data.Req_ID, datatype: 'json' });
                    $("#jqGridDetails").jqGrid('setCaption', 'Requisition Detail For :: <b style="color: Red">' + data.Job + '</b>');
                    $("#jqGridDetails").trigger("reloadGrid");
                }
            },
            onSortCol: clearSelection,
            onPaging: clearSelection,
            pager: "#jqGridPager"
        });


    });
    // detail grid

    $("#jqGridDetails").jqGrid({
        url: '@Url.Action("RequisitionDetailGrid")',
        mtype: "GET",
        datatype: "json",
        page: 1,

        colModel: [
            { key: true, name: 'Req_ID_Det', index: 'Req_ID_Det', label: 'Req Det ID', hidden: true, editable: true, align: "center", width: 12 },
            { name: 'ReqNo', index: 'ReqNo', label: 'Req No', hidden: true, align: "left", width: 40 },
            { name: 'SrNo', index: 'SrNo', label: 'Sr No',  align: "left", width: 3 },
            { name: 'GL_Year', index: 'GL_Year', hidden:true,editable:true, label: 'GL_Year', width: 5 },
            { name: 'ItemDesc', index: 'ItemDesc', label: 'Item Desciption', width: 20 },
            { name: 'Qty', index: 'Qty', label: 'Qty', width: 2 },
            { name: 'Remarks', index: 'Remarks', label: 'Remarks', width: 10 },

            {
                name: 'Req_ID_Det', label: '', search: false, width: '2', formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                    return MethodFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject);
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'Req_ID_Det', label: '', search: false, width: '2', formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                    return MethodDelete(cellvalue, options, rowObject);
                }
            },


        ],
        autowidth: true,
        shrinkToFit: true,
        navOptions: {
            reloadGridOptions: { fromServer: true }
        },
        rowNum: 5,
        loadonce: true,
        height: '100',
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: 'Requisition Detail',
        emptyrecords: 'No Records are Available to Display',
        pager: "#jqGridDetailsPager"
    });

    function clearSelection() {
        jQuery("#jqGridDetails").jqGrid('setGridParam', { url: "RequisitionDetailGrid", datatype: 'json' }); // the last setting is for demo purpose only
        jQuery("#jqGridDetails").jqGrid('setCaption', 'Detail Grid:: none');
        jQuery("#jqGridDetails").trigger("reloadGrid");

    }

    function MethodFormatter(cellValue, options, rowObject) {
        var selectedRowId = options.rowId;
        return '<a href="javascript:getbyID(' + selectedRowId + ')" style="color: #3366ff" id="' + selectedRowId + '" >Edit</a>';
    }
    function MethodDelete(cellValue, options, rowObject) {
        var selectedRowId = options.rowId;
        return '<a href="javascript:ReqDelete(' + selectedRowId + ')" style="color: #3366ff" id="' + selectedRowId + '" >Delete</a>';
    }
```

HTML

```
 <!--Requsitition Detail Update Model-->
        <div class="modal fade" id="ReqMainUpdateModel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-notify modal-info" role="document">
                <!--Content-->

                <div class="modal-content">
                    <!--Header-->
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <p class="heading lead">Update Requisition Main</p>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true" class="white-text">&times;</span>
                        </button>

                    </div>

                    <form id="NewOrderForm">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col" id="Req_ID">

                                    <div class="md-form">

                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Req_ID, new { @class = "form-control mr-sm-3", @id = "txtReqIDmain", Required = true })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <!-- Requisition Date-->
                                    <label for="lblReqDate">Req Date</label>
                                    <div class="md-form">

                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ReqDate, new { @class = "form-control mr-sm-3", @id = "txtReqDateMain" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <label for="lblJOB"> JOB</label>
                                    <div class="md-form">
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Job, new { @class = "form-control mr-sm-3", @id = "txtReqjOBMain" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <label for="lblApprovedBy"> Approved By </label>
                                    <div class="md-form">
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Approvedby, new { @class = "form-control mr-sm-3", @id = "txtApprovedByMain" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <label for="lblApproved"> Approved </label>
                                    <div class="md-form">
                                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsApproved, new { @class = "form-control mr-sm-3", @id = "txtIsApprovedMain" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button id="ReqMainUpdate" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="RequisitionDetail_Update();">Update Record</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>



                </div>

                <!--/.Content-->
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand correctly your question. Do you mean call of global `ReqMainUpdateMethod` function inside of `Req_ID` column if you write about "edit button link"? JavaScript supports `onclick` event. It supports [event bubbling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_bubbling). Thus if no onclick event handler registered on internal element like `<a>` or `<td>` then onclick handler will be triggered on the outer `<table>` element and `onSelectRow` will be called. I guess that your current implementation of `ReqMainUpdateMethod` stop event propagation.

Comment: my current method ReqMainUpdateMethos Stop when i use Edit button link.